# Trailing slash issue using mod_rewrite for SEO friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I consider myself reasonably competent with PHP. I am, however, completely and totally lost when it comes to mod_rewrite.

I have a URL structure that works like the following:

```
http://site/something/something-else/the-actual-page/
```

that redirects to:

```
http://site/index.php?page=the-actual-page
```

It's only ever the final 'folder' that is passed to the script. The preceding 'folders' (if any) are for SEO and structure purposes.

If there is a preceding folder "promotion" then it redirects to a separate file. This is along the lines of:

```
http://site/promotion/campaign-name/
```

redirecting to

```
http://site/promotion.php?campaign=campaign-name
```

I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^promotion/(.*)/$ promotion.php?params=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works as intended, with links redirecting properly EXCEPT when there is no trailing slash. For example

```
http://site/something/thepage/
```

will work, whilst

```
http://site/something/thepage
```

will not.

To solve this problem I'm attempting to set up a 301 that redirects any URI without a trailing slash to a URI with a trailing slash.

The code below (placed above the other rules) works to a degree, but I lose folder data.

Code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The problem?

```
http://site/something/thepage
```

redirects to

```
http://site/thepage/
```

I'm afraid all the googling in the world is not helping me, as I cannot wrap my brain around mod_rewrite at all!

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be better off using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
# ... your other rerites
```

If you'd like to reverse it and strip the trailing slash instead, then use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

You'd then need to change your rewrite accordingly:

```
RewriteRule ^promotion/(.*)$ /promotion.php?params=$1 [L]
```